# impossible to add, a recording

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to add a recording in my form Revision, but it misses a few things? I can add a recording via phpmyadmin but not on my form.

**create.revision**

[image]

**index.revision**

[image]

Here is, below my function store():

```
public function store(revisionRequest $request)
    {

        $date_revision_start = $request->get('date_revision_start');
        $date_revision_end = $request->get('date_revision_end');
        $garage = $request->get('garage');
        $fk_motorbike = $request->get('fk_motorbike');



        $conflict = Revision::whereDate('fk_motorbike', $request->get('fk_motorbike'))->whereDate('date_revision_start', "<=" , $date_revision_start);

        $conflict2 = Revision::whereDate('fk_motorbike', $request->get('fk_motorbike'))->whereDate('date_revision_start', "<=" , $date_revision_end)->whereDate('date_revision_end', ">=", $date_revision_end)->first();
        dd($conflict);

        if(isset($conflict2) || isset($conflict)){
            return redirect()->route('revisions.index')
             ->with('error', 'duplicate');
        }


       else{
        Revision::create($request->all());
            return redirect()->route('revisions.index')
                ->with('success', 'new data created successfully');
        }

    }
```

I don't understand the error ???

[image]

I thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Remove the dd($conflict) línea. It s not an error

Comment: Also, you forget the ->first() after $conflict = Revision::whereDate('fk_motorbike', $request->get('fk_motorbike'))->whereDate('date_revision_start', "<=" , $date_revision_start);

Comment: is `fk_motorbike` a `date` column? it seems not.

Comment: @zahid hasan emon: ` fk_motorbike` is the numero of the bike via the table motorbike. Why ?

Comment: the zahid hasan emon 's observation makes sense. Note that you are using whereDate (which is to compare dates) and you should use just where.

Comment: yeah just use `where` clause.

Comment: thank you for your help the friends, my problem is solved.^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an incomplete line of code here:

```
$conflict = Revision::whereDate('fk_motorbike', $request->get('fk_motorbike'))
->whereDate('date_revision_start', "<=" , $date_revision_start);
```

This does not go to a query, it is just a **Builder** object waiting for the final part of the code so it can become a query.  Thus, you get the **Builder** object when you dump it.  To fix, make this like the line below it, which was correct in your code:

```
$conflict = Revision::where('fk_motorbike', $request->get('fk_motorbike'))
->whereDate('date_revision_start', "<=" , $date_revision_start)
->whereDate('date_revision_end', ">=", $date_revision_start)
->first();
```

Also, as noted in the comments by @zahid hasan emon and @porloscerros Ψ, the `whereDate` should only be on the date fields, not the FK field.

The problem is that because this was incomplete, you are returning a builder object **every time** from the first `$conflict` code that you have now.  This means it is **always** going to be non-null.  So, when you get to the check to see if there is a conflict here:

```
if(isset($conflict2) || isset($conflict)){ ... }
```

this will **always** return a 'duplicate' error since `$conflict` is always going to be set as a non-null object (since it is a builder object and not a query return).

Comment: :-) !! Thank you a lot it works now , I will read your explanations to better understand.